# Django problems with primary keys and data inserts

Tags: python, mysql, django

My console shows this problem when trying to push data into my db

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

My **views.py** class:

```
def routineInput(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateRoutine(request.POST)
    query = request.POST["name_of_routine"]
    newEntry = Todolist(str(query))
    #newEntry.name = ()
    if form.is_valid():
        newEntry.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/saved/')
else:
    form = CreateRoutine()
```

This is my **models.py** class:

```
class Todolist(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name =  models.TextField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
```

The `newEntry = Todolist(str(query))` is my problem. If I change it to `newEntry = Todolist(1, str(query))` my code works. But in the last case my code pushes the integer into the "id" field although it should be my auto increment primary key.

Without the integer in my function my browser throws me this message:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do `newEntry = ToDoList(name=str(query))` or define the `create` method in the model yourself to customise instance creation.

```
from django.db import models

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name =  models.TextField()

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, created_at=None, updated_at=None):
        list = cls(name=name, created_at=created_at, updated_at=updated_at)
        # do something with the insatnce
        return list

newEntry = ToDoList.create(name=str(query))
```

Without keyword argument `name=` the constructor expects integer for `id` (because it's first positional argument) whereas you pass a string.